# Pug: toggle class based on filename

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I am using Pug to build out some html files, and I have a navbar that is located in a `partials/nav.pug` file.

I would like when I run:

```
pug.renderFile('file1.pug', {file: 'file1'});
pug.renderFile('file2.pug', {file: 'file2'});
```

Then in the `file1.html` file my item in the nav gets the active class if you are on the page `/file1.html`:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="">File 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">File 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then in `file2.html` the active class is on the second element if you're on the page `/file2.html`.

Here is a basic guess of how I think this could be done (I don't really know how this would be done in pug):

```
ul
    li(class=#{file} == 'file1.html' ? 'active' : ''): a(href='/file2.html') File 1
    li(class=#{file} == 'file2.html' ? 'active' : ''): a(href='/file1.html') File 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well It was basically exactly what I thought, just needed to move the braces and use a `$` in front of them [here is the doc describing that](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2305):

```
ul
    li(class=`${file == 'file1.html' ? 'active' : ''}`): a(href='/file2.html') File 1
    li(class=`${file == 'file2.html' ? 'active' : ''}`): a(href='/file1.html') File 2
```